# GridBag Constraint adds only through class's constructor but not with method

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout

Okay, so I have 3 methods to add 2 panels and 1 button and at the same time, it's gridbag constraint. However, when I call the 3 methods in the class's constructor it won't apply any of the constraints.

It's able to add the components and apply the constraints if I put the constraints code within the constructor instead of method calls. I don't know why. Is it not possible to add components and constraints using methods and put it inside the constructor?

This doesn't work(won't arrange the components by x and y):

```
package HomeTab;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

public class HomeTopPanel extends JPanel {

private final JButton myAccountButton = new JButton("My Account");
private final JPanel leftPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
private final JPanel rightPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
private final Border leftPanelLineBorder = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 2);
private final Border rightPanelLineBorder = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 2);
GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

//CONSTRUCTOR
public HomeTopPanel(){
    //METHOD CALLS
    constructMyAccountButton();
    constructPanels();
    setLeftRightPanelBorders();
    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());   
}

public final void constructMyAccountButton(){
    gbc.gridx = 1; gbc.gridy = 0; 
        this.add(myAccountButton,gbc);
}

public final void constructPanels(){
    leftPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, 300));
    gbc.gridx = 0; gbc.gridy = 0; 
        this.add(leftPanel,gbc);

    rightPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 500));    
    gbc.gridx = 2; gbc.gridy = 0; 
        this.add(rightPanel,gbc);
}

private void setLeftRightPanelBorders(){
    leftPanel.setBorder(leftPanelLineBorder);
    rightPanel.setBorder(rightPanelLineBorder);
    this.setBorder(leftPanelLineBorder);
}
}
```

But If I put the gridx and gridy position of components within the constructor, it does the trick. I want to use methods to accomplish it instead of putting the constraints inside the constructor.

Output where constraints didn't apply:

[image]

This is what works:

```
public HomeTopPanel(){
    //METHOD CALLS
    setLeftRightPanelBorders();
    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    gbc.gridx = 1; gbc.gridy = 0; 
        this.add(myAccountButton,gbc);
    leftPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, 300));
    gbc.gridx = 0; gbc.gridy = 0; 
        this.add(leftPanel,gbc);
    rightPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 500));    
    gbc.gridx = 2; gbc.gridy = 0; 
        this.add(rightPanel,gbc);
}
```

Desired Output / Correct Output:

[image]

Thanks in advanced. Basically, my question is how I can use methods / method calls within the constructor to apply the constraints and add the panels and button.

Comment: Call `setLayout(new GridBagLayout());` before you try adding the components.  The constraints are been ignored by the default layout manager, `FlowLayout`

Answer (score 2):

Call `setLayout(new GridBagLayout());` before you try adding the components.  The constraints are been ignored by the default layout manager, `FlowLayout`

```
public HomeTopPanel(){
    //METHOD CALLS
    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());   
    constructMyAccountButton();
    constructPanels();
    setLeftRightPanelBorders();
}
```

Comment: thank you very much!!. I didn't know I have to set the Layout before adding components and constraints. I thought that setting a panel with new GridBagLayout() during instantiation is enough. I appreciate this quick answer and made things clear now. Thanks again.